# How to make a list in python that counts its entries in hours and minutes?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list as such:

`list = [1.24, 3.54, 6.59]`

Say I want to add two of these list objects together -- *i.e* `3.54 + 6.59`. How would I add those, treating them as hours and minutes (`hh.mm`)?

Answer (score 1):

One possible thing to do is to use `datetime.timedelta`.

to transform your floats into timedelta, you can do :

```
from datetime import timedelta
l = [1.24, 3.54, 6.59]
transformed = [timedelta(hours=int(i), minutes=(i % 1) * 100) for i in l]
```

Then you just need to sum the list :

```
sum(transformed, timedelta(0, 0))
```

Comment: the sum returns 12 hours 16 minutes not 12 hours 17 minutes as it should be.

Comment: in fact this is the `int((i - int(i)) * 100) that leads to a bad round. You can use the `i%1*100` trick

Answer (score 0):

You should never name your variables like predefined data structures (list in this case).

One way to solve it is to simply convert to minutes sum up and then convert back to the format you have:

```
l = [1.24, 3.54, 6.59]

res = 0
for i in l:
  res += i//1*60 + i%1*100

print(res/60//1, 'hours',  res%60, 'minutes')
#12.0 hours 17.0 minutes
```